# Custom Attributes on Properties returning nothing

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to access data from a custom attribute applied to a property, I just keep returning nothing all the time. Here is my latest attempt.

The Attribute:

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)>
Public Class TestAttribute
Inherits System.Attribute

Public Property name As String

Sub New(ByVal dirName As String)
    name = dirName
End Sub

End Class
```

The Property:

```
<Test("My Awesome Attribute")>
Public Property testProperty As String
```

The Call:

```
    testProperty = "Blah Blah"

    Try


        Dim attr As System.Attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(testProperty.GetType(), GetType(TestAttribute))
        Dim testAttr As TestAttribute = CType(attr, TestAttribute)

        Console.WriteLine(testAttr.name)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130863(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Same Axe, I was led to a page I haddn't seen and helped me work out what I was doing wrong. I had tried the GetProperty route but obviously the wrong way. I am now using this which works.

The Attribute:

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)>
Public Class TestAttribute
Inherits System.Attribute

Public Property name As String

Sub New(ByVal dirName As String)
    name = dirName
End Sub

End Class
```

The Property:

```
<Test("My Awesome Attribute")>
Public Property testProperty As String
```

The Call:

```
    testProperty = "Blah Blah"

    Try


        Dim pinfo As PropertyInfo = Me.GetType().GetProperty("testProperty")


        Dim attr As System.Attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(pinfo, GetType(TestAttribute))
        Dim testAttr As TestAttribute = CType(attr, TestAttribute)

        Console.WriteLine(testAttr.name)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Output:

```
My Awesome Attribute
```